# Jenkins Pipeline Plugin with Parallel jobs UI

Tags: jenkins, build-pipeline-plugin, build-pipeline

I have an issue with my jenkins build pipeline whereby at each for in the pipeline, I see duplicate flows, which are never used. The pipeline runs correctly, and it's only a UI issue, but it'd kind of annoying and limits the number of builds I can see in one view. I've tried a few different plugins but have had the same issue with all of them, so I guess it's some issue with the BuildPipeline plugin.

What my pipeline looks like:
[image: Jenkins Build Pipeline]

What it should ideally look like:
[image: Ideal Build Pipeline View]

Comment: Btw this is is _not_ [tag:jenkins-pipeline], which is probably the solution that you want to use nowadays.

Comment: Oh? My bad. I'll try actually using the thing I think I'm using and see if that helps. Thanks!